# What is relief amount in grooving operation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, machining, cnc, lathe

Can somebody please explain what relief amount at the end of cut in a grooving operation on lathe is?

Answer (score 1):

A groove will have a very slight internal radius in its corner, but if this is undesirable, then a relief grooving tool is used to remove this material. The relief grooving tool comes in at 45 Deg to cut as shown:

[image]